# Layout designer could not be loaded

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin; after several hours spent installing and reinstalling, trying to deploy a Hello Android app, I made it! However, when I try to open the app layout, I encounter this error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException: No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    VisualStudioWorkspace
    RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.GetCodeModelBridge() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.cs:line 154
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.get_CodeModelBridge()
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.<UpdateDesignerResourceIds>d__175.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.<EnsureLoaded>d__139.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidRenderSession.<InitSession>d__105.MoveNext()
```

What to do guys?

Comment: I'd open a bug in xamarin's bugzilla

Comment: Thanks, solution is to delete cache in :C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache